# How to install and use php-cgi

Tags: php, lamp

I have installed LAMP server via `tasksel`. Where is PHP directory?

How to install and use `php-cgi` if I don't have it inside PHP directory (I need to copy `php-cgi` file from there)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using `tasksel` You'll find php scattered throughout. However, if you're trying to use php-cgi, Ubuntu packages have that already configured.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi libapache2-mod-php5
```

You can then enable apache to use it with:

```
sudo a2enmod php5-cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Very VERY rarely will you ever need to copy files around to get something packaged working.

Comment: Ok, and where is `php-cgi`?

Comment: After you install it, you'll find it in `/usr/bin/php5-cgi` HOWEVER I REITERATE, you should never need to move files from packages, ever. So whatever you're doing is likely not written to be run on a Debian/Ubuntu system. Maybe you should expand your question to WHY you have to move this file.